# Wordpress - send variable from page to theme function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function in the theme function file that pulls JSON data and creates a shortcode that I use in a page

My question is how to pass the RID=Value from a page using the shortcode
[json_employees] and send the RID back to the function?

```
function foobar2_func( $atts ){
ob_start();
$url = 'https://jdublu.com/api/wrsc/json_employee.php?RID=17965'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$items = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $items);
$items = json_decode($data, true); 
?>
add_shortcode( 'json_employees', 'foobar2_func' );
```

Comment: Did you try with `shortcode_atts`?

Answer (score 0):

your shortcode should be

```
[json_employees RID='17965']
```

and shortcode function is

```
function foobar2_func( $atts ){
    ob_start();
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'RID' => 'id',
    ), $atts );

    $url = 'https://jdublu.com/api/wrsc/json_employee.php?RID='.esc_attr($atts['RID']); 
    $data = file_get_contents($url); 
    $items = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $items);
    $items = json_decode($data, true); 
    return $items;
}
add_shortcode( 'json_employees', 'foobar2_func' );
```

Comment: thanks but is not getting the RID in the function, what else could be?

Comment: Print this variable $atts and check

Answer (score 0):

```
    function foobar2_func( $atts ){
        ob_start();
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'RID' => 'id',
        ), $atts );

        $url = 'https://jdublu.com/api/wrsc/json_employee.php?RID='.esc_attr($atts['RID']); 
        $data = file_get_contents($url); 
        $items = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $items);
        $items = json_decode($data, true); 
        return $items;
        print_r ($atts);
    }
    add_shortcode( 'json_employees', 'foobar2_func' );

    and in the wordpress page
    [json_employees RID='17965']

here is the page to test it http://bahiacr.com/test_json/
```

Comment: function foobar2_func( $atts ){
        ob_start();
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'RID' => 'id',
        ), $atts );

        $url = 'https://jdublu.com/api/wrsc/json_employee.php?RID='.esc_attr($atts['RID']); 
        $data = file_get_contents($url); 
        $items = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $items);
        $items = json_decode($data, true); 
        return $items;
        print_r ($atts);
    }
    add_shortcode( 'json_employees', 'foobar2_func' );

    and in the wordpress page
    [json_employees RID='17965']
http://bahiacr.com/test_json/